# Flood Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Meu objetivo é que a pessoa digite um texto. Vamos supor que numa `textbox` com `multiline=true`, e nesse texto, a cada quebra de linha, essa linha seja tratada diferente, tipo, a cada frase no `textbox` eu consiga executar uma função diferente se quiser. Simplesmente usar algum comando referente ao texto incorpora tudo escrito na `textbox`, e eu queria linha por linha.

Outro exemplo: Vamos supor que eu queira fazer um *flooder*, aí a pessoa digita o que quer pra ser dito no `textbox` e se eu usar em um *Timer*:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(TextBox1.Text, True)
    SendKeys.Send("^v{ENTER}")
```

Com esse código eu ia pegar o que foi escrito no `textbox1` e assim que o mouse dela passasse por alguma caixa de diálogo, a mensagem seria enviada, porém enviaria todas as frases da pessoa de uma vez, e eu quero que envie uma por uma separadamente, assim eu conseguiria até mesmo adicionar um intervalo de envio entre elas.

A ferramenta não precisa ser exatamente uma `textbox`, pode ser o que funcionar melhor e mais simples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está muito confusa sua pergunta, mas entendi que você **quer separar as linhas e executar comandos nestas linhas separadas**, pois bem, vamos lá.

Vamos criar um método que executa ações em uma única linha, para não sobrecarregar muito apenas um método:

```
Public Sub EvaluateLine(ByVal linha As String)
    Dim ItemsDaLinha As String() = linha.Split(" ")  ' Divide a linha por espaços
    Select Case ItemsDaLinha(0).ToLower()            ' Pega o primeiro item da linha
        Case "MandarMensagem"                        ' Quando o primeiro statement for um "EnviarMensagem"
            Dim ParaQuem$ = ItemsDaLinha(1)          ' Pega o primeiro argumento da linha
            If (String.IsNullOrWhitespace(ParaQuem)  ' Se o primeiro argumento for vazio ou nada...
                 Exit Sub                            ' Saia do método
            End If
            Dim Conteudo$ = linha.Substring(Len(ItemsDaLinha(0)) + Len(ItemsDaLinha(1)))
            Clipboard.SetString(Conteudo)            ' Obtém o conteúdo do código e joga para a área de transferência
     End Select
End Sub
```

No método acima, você vai emulando cada linha para um item do `Case`. [Aprenda como usar Select...Case aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement). Nisso, aqui irá um exemplo básico para uma linha de código:

```
MandarMensagem Fulano Olá, mundo!
```

Nessa mensagem acima, o método acima iria interpretar `MandarMensagem` como o primeiro índice de `ItemsDaLinha()`, `Fulano` como segundo índice, e por fim, `Olá, mundo!` o `Conteudo`.

---

Agora, para encorporar **todas as linhas da TextBox** e que `EvaluateLine` execute todas estas linhas, implemente este método e chame-o quando for executar a série de comandos:

```
Public Sub PerformText(ByVal code As String)
     ' Cria uma lista com todas as linhas de 'code'
     Dim linhas As String() = code.Split(Environment.NewLine)
     ' Faz um loop e executa todas as linhas
     For Each linhaAtual As String In linhas
           ' Chama o método que executa a linha
           EvaluateLine(linhaAtual)
     Next
End Sub
```

Pronto. Agora para executar todas estas linhas, chame este método `PerformText` com o texto do `TextBox` como argumento:

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal obj As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Call PerformText(TextBox1.Text)
End Sub
```

---

Para detectar se o mouse está por cima de algum componente, utilize o evento [MouseHover](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover(v=vs.110).aspx).